# trying to get the latitude and longitude of the users on my website built on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

i tried to get the latitude and longitude of the users but i get some error and i'm not even sure about the code either are also right but i'm really trying to get user's latitude and longitude and associate them with some conditions. here are the code in the controller.
[image: Controller code]

then we have the codes in the views:
[image: View code]

Comment: You should post code instead of images.

Answer (score 2):

Free service from [ip-api.com](https://ip-api.com) should work. Append your IP and it returns almost everything you need.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
...

$ip = request()->ip();                // something like 127.0.0.1
$url = "http://ip-api.com/" . $ip;    // http://ip-api.com/127.0.0.1
$data = Http::get($url);              // will return json with detailed data
```

Rest just modify yourself, either modify only specific data or throw all to view. **Make sure to not doing requests more than 150/minute or you will get banned and cannot do another requests**